# ColdFusion 10 serializeJSON turning yes/no strings to boolean values--how to stop it?

Tags: sql-server, json, coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-10

I have a Stored Procedure, MS SQL Server, one of the columns returned is a string, "yes" or "no."  So far, so good.  I'm creating a JSON string in ColdFusion 10 and will eventually be kicking that out to jQuery/Bootstrap to put in a table.  If I call `writeOutput("SP suitable text: " & spResults.rg_suitable_text[i]);` on the output of the SP, (and this is a computed value, not an actual column with an actual datatype in TSQL,) it writes what it should, ie yes or no.  However, in constructing an array to be serialized as JSON, `rg_suitable_text=spResults.rg_suitable_text[i]` and so on, if I use a REST client for Google or Firefox and view just the raw JSON output from ColdFusion, it shows true/false.  I even tried creating a new variable and hard-coding:

```
var solicit="No";
if(spResults.rg_suitable_text[i] EQ true OR trim(spResults.rg_suitable_text[i]) EQ "true")
{
    solicit="Yes";
}
```

and tagging that onto my array, but the same thing happens.  It looks like ColdFusion 11 supports a way to get around this, but this is a work project, so that's not an option.  Is there an edit I can make to the above block that would say, "ColdFusion 10, I don't care what you want, this is a string and treat it like a blasted string, dangit!"

Comment: crappy solution, but we resorted to adding a space before these values, so it wouldn't change the data type.

Comment: Spaces do echo into the HTML stream, (so I have `<td> Yes </td>`,) but I suppose it cannot be avoided.  This will work for now, but I'm going to leave the question open for a bit in case someone has a less hack-tastic solution.  Also noting, for anyone who Googles their way over here, trying to throw a trim() call in before returning leaves the same problem.  I'm guessing this is a defect in the serializeJSON method in CF10.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your bottom line question (the last sentence of your post), the answer is: *no*.

You can mess around with the data so as to trick ColdFusion into thinking it's a string not a boolean, but that is not a very good approach.

You basically need to use something other than ColdFusion to create your JSON strings. ColdFusion has been rife with JSON bugs, pretty much asking its JSON offering not fit for purpose. I think *most* of the bugs found have been fixed in CF11 though, as you have noticed.

I've not used it in prod., but I had a reasonable amount of proof-of-concept success using [Google's GSON API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for building JSON out of CFML data.

Comment: Issue is still marked as Closed/Fixed, sweet Jesus why!!!? https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3337394

Answer (score 3):

[JsonSerializer.cfc](https://github.com/bennadel/JsonSerializer.cfc) on github can process your "this is a string and treat it like a blasted string, dangit!" request.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2505-jsonserializer-cfc-a-data-serialization-utility-for-coldfusion.htm

Example code:

```
serializer = new lib.JsonSerializer()
    .asInteger( "age" )
    .asAny( "createdAt" )
    .asDate( "dateOfBirth" )
    .asString( "favoriteColor" )
    .asInteger( "favoriteNumbers" )
    .asString( "firstName" )
    .asString( "lastName" )
    .asString( "nickName" )
    .exclude( "password" );

tricia = {
    FIRSTNAME = "Tricia",
    LASTNAME = "Smith",
    DATEOFBIRTH = dateConvert( "local2utc", "1975/01/01" ),
    NICKNAME = "Trish",
    FAVORITECOLOR = "333333",
    FAVORITENUMBERS = [ true, 4.0, 137, false ],
    AGE = 38,
    CREATEDAT = now(),
    PASSWORD = "I<3ColdFusion&Cookies"
};

writeDump(serializer.serialize( tricia ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and decided to modify my SQL statement that was pulling the "No" string values.  Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <colname> = 'NO' THEN 'NON' ELSE <colname> AS <colname>, <colname2>, etc...
```

Then I handle the string value "NON" from the JSON as I would handle a "NO" case.

Not the most elegant solution, but it seemed to work in my application.